# Computing Average In a Data Table in Python

Tags: python, dataframe

Define the "data science experience" of a given person as the person's largest score among Regression, Classification, and Clustering. Compute the average data science experience among all MBA students.

The prompt here kind of confuses me when it says "the person's largest score among Regression, Classification, and Clustering." My approach was to add those 3 numbers together in a new column and find the mean of them along with every other MBA student.

Below was my attempt, but this returns the mean of every single MBA student in 1 row of the new column as opposed to the mean of that individual in their row.

```
def MbaAvgExp(row):
    if row['Program']=='MBA':
        return df['Regression']+df['Classification']+df['Clustering'].mean()
    else:
        return 0

df['MbaAvgExp']=df.apply(MbaAvgExp, axis=1)
df
```

What can I do to fix this, and if you think my understanding of the prompt is incorrect please explain what I'm missing.

[image: Data Table]

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should change the variable names in the `if` case, and there is also a pair of parentheses that you may want to add within the return statement of that case.